# How do I get a window that display mu code in VS code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, output

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm trying to do a simple project using VS Code, just to practice the basic.
And I can't get my code to output anything. When I run my code the terminal give me [], when it should return an interactive game . (I did the debugger and no mistake in my code)
If you could tell me what I'm doing wrong would be must appreciate.

```js
let board = [
  ["X"],
  ["O"],
  ["O"]
  ['X'],
  ['O'],
  ['O']
  ['O'],
  ['X'],
  ['X']
];

let player1 = "X";
let player2 = "O";

function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  let w = width / 3;
  let h = height / 3;

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      let x = w * i;
      let y = h * j;
      let spot = board[i][j];
      textSize(40);
      text(spot, x, y);
    }
  }
}
```

I copied this from a tic tac toe video to test VS Code and I can't keep going as I can't see the output of my code.

Comment: I made your code a Stack Snippet so you could click the Run code snippet button and see that nothing prints here either. If you look closely, you can see that there is nothing that calls `setup()` or `draw()`. That's okay, because they would throw errors, since `createCanvas` and `background` are not defined and would immediately throw errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply I'll keep working on it and hopefully I can get something out of it.